# why do I receive the errror

Tags: excel, perl, xls, xlsx

in my code, I have a function which verifies if a cell from an worksheet contains valid values, meaning:
1. it contains something.
2. the contained value is not SPACE, TAB or ENTER.

when i am just checking the function within a print (to print the value returned by the function for a single cell), apparently, everything works fine.
when I am integrating the "print of the result" into a while loop, for checking a range of cells, it received the error message: `Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at D:\test.pl`

here is my code:

```
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;

my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new();

sub check_cell($) {
    my ( $worksheet, $a, $b ) = @_;
    if ( $worksheet->get_cell( $a, $b )
        or not ord( $worksheet->get_cell( $a, $b )->value() ) ~~ [ 32, 9, 10 ] )
    {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

my $workbook = $parser->parse('D:\test.pl data.xlsx');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet(0);

my $i = 8;

while ( &check_cell( $worksheet, $i, 0 ) ) {
    print &check_cell( $worksheet, $i, 0 ), "\n";
    $i++;
}
```

if I remove the while and index increment, everything works fine.

Can anyone tell me why the error occurs in 1st case?

Thank you.

Comment: Minor style note -- you're using a prototype on `check_cell($)`, and then explicitly telling perl to ignore the prototype with the ampersand `&check_cell(...)`.  You might want to remove both the `($)` and the `&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `$worksheet->get_cell($a, $b)` doesn't return a defined value, you can't call `->value` on the undefined value it returned. Don't you want to use `and` instead of `or` in the condition?

Comment: in my case, the `-> value()` returns a defined value.

Comment: @mikcutu, The program died because `->value` couldn't be called. Saying a function that was never called returned a defined value makes no sense.

Comment: @ikegami, Do you want to say that the problem comes from the fact that I am calling the bun into the while loop?

Comment: @mikcutu: `value` is a method. It needs an object to be called on. if `get_cell` returns `undef`, there's no object.

Comment: @choroba, @ikegami, I got it! The problem occurs because, indeed, after the `while` loops through entire cell-range which contains values, it goes to the cell, outside the range, where there are no more values, and normally, is should exit; but it exists with this error. Thank you guys for the help.

Answer (score 2):

When you compare two strings for equallity, you have to use `eq`, not `==`

```
while( check_cell($worksheet, $i, 0) eq "correct cell" ) {
   #...
};
```

Also, it's more natural to return 0 or 1 in your `check_cell` sub, so you haven't to test the result in `while` loop:

```
sub check_cell {
   # return 1 if it's ok, else 0
}

while( check_cell($worksheet, $i, 0) ) {
   #...
};
```

And the smartmatch operator `~~` has been marked as experimental since Perl 5.18.0

Answer (score 1):

in this case, it worked modifying the condition:

instead of this:

```
if ( $worksheet->get_cell( $a, $b )
        or not ord( $worksheet->get_cell( $a, $b )->value() ) ~~ [ 32, 9, 10 ] )
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

I used:

```
    if ( $worksheet -> get_cell($a, $b) ) {
        if ( not ord($worksheet -> get_cell($a, $b) -> value()) ~~ [32, 9, 10] ){
        return 1;
        }
    }
```

and the scrit exits without any error.

Thank you guys for your help.